# Extract date if found certain keywords

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a large paragraph of text, for example:

```
mytext <- "Date joined: some long text here 01/02/2012. Some more long text here, then commencement date: 1/5/2012. More info at the end."
```

I would like to extract all the dates found in any sentences that contain either the word "Date joined" or "commencement date"

So my result would be 1/5/2012 and 01/02/2012.

I tried a few patterns with regex but havent been successful so far.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: You could use `stringi::stri_extract_all(mytext, regex = "\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+")`, but I have the feeling that you need something more complicated. This only extracts everything in a date like format. Could you create a more extended example and your expected output with this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original text you provided:

```
mytext <- "Date joined: some long text here 01/02/2012. Some more long text here, then commencement date: 1/5/2012. More info at the end."
```

First split the text at the periods and return a vector of sentences.

```
sentences <- strsplit(mytext,".",fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
```

Then we select only those sentences with the phrases you noted.

```
relevant <- sentences[grepl("Date joined|commencement date",sentences)]
```

Now we can search for the dates:

```
unlist(regmatches(relevant,gregexpr("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}",relevant)))
```

This produces the vector:

```
[1] "01/02/2012" "1/5/2012"
```

Depending on how widely the date format varies you may have to adjust this regular expressions pattern.  Also, I used exactly the phrases (with capitalization) you provided to select the sentences.  If the phrases are not case-sensitive then you will want to use the `ignore.case=TRUE` option when selecting your sentences with these phrases.

UPDATE:  The original poster asked how to extract the first date found in each relevant sentence.  I modified the code to provide a relevant example for that situation and to use sapply.

```
mytext <- "Date joined: some long text here 01/02/2012 and also here 05/13/1899. Some more long text here, then commencement date: 1/5/2012 and also 2/3/4567. More info at the end."
sentences <- strsplit(mytext,".",fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
relevant <- sentences[grepl("Date joined|commencement date",sentences)]
the_dates <- regmatches(relevant,gregexpr("[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}",relevant))
the_first_dates <- sapply(the_dates,function(z) z[1])
```

In `the_first_dates` we now have

```
[1] "01/02/2012" "1/5/2012"
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works if there is only one date in each sentence. What if there are more than two dates in each sentence and I only want to pick up the first one after the word is matched?

Comment: Hi southwind: updated the code above to address the modification.  Cheers!